# Replace self closing div with proper div closing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, xslt-1.0

I have a HTML string like below,

**Code**

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:-20px" /> 
<div style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0px 3px; float: left;" class="Fav aLogin" title="Bookmark" />
```

The above html prepared by XSLT transform and I am trying to add the above html into existing div element dynamically. The problem here's when it rendered then the closing div is recognized. I found that self closing is NOT valid for div element and it should be proper closing .

I tried changing the xml output to the following but still the self closing tag is appearing.

**Code**

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
<xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes" />
```

So, I need a way to replace the tags which is self closing first in the HTML string then add it to the DOM. Please help to suggest.

NOTE: I hv found some ways to add some dummy elements/text within the self closing div but  it is NOT feasible in my case as i have so many XSLT which has self closing tags in it.

Comment: Just to clarify, self closing div's ARE valid in xhtml, just not in HTML 4.x.

Comment: Is each line of the div list  self-closing div markup without intended text content? i.e. each line begins `<div` and ends ` />` ? If so, I'd be inclned to pre-process the list to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

If the list has markup for a self-closing div on each line without intended display text, I'd pre-process a copy of the list to replace  `/>` with `></div>`;

**Solution 1, Pre-process using javascript**

My snippet example `split`s the list into an array, each element being markup for one self-closing div. The `array.map` method is then used to create a new array where each element has had the string replacement made:

```js
const list = `<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:-20px" /> 
<div style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0px 3px; float: left;" class="Fav aLogin" title="Bookmark" />
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:-20px" /> 
<div style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0px 3px; float: left;" class="Fav aLogin" title="Bookmark" />`;

divArray = list.split('\n');

const newDivs = divArray.map(x => x.replace(" />", "></div>"));

document.getElementById('output').innerText = newDivs.join("\n");
```

```css
#output {

white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Solution 2: preprocess using `sed` on command line**

If you save a file containing the list of self closing div markup as (e.g) `selfClose.txt`, you can make the required substitutions on the command line, saving the new list to (e.g) `output.txt` using the stream editor `sed` on the command line:

```
sed 's/ \/\>/\>\<\/div\>/g' selfClose.txt > output.file
```

Note the `/`, `>`, and `<` characters all have to be escaped in the regular expression used for the replacement.

The generic format would be:

```
sed 's/old-text/new-text/g' oldFile > newFile
```

The `s` flag is for substitute, and the `g` flag is for global - replacing all occurrences.